# Ruby version is not correctly detected and causes dependency issue when installing gem package

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm using Ruby 1.9, through RVM:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
```

However, trying to install [Apiaryio](https://github.com/apiaryio/apiary-client) I get the following error:

```
$ sudo gem install apiaryio
ERROR:  Error installing apiaryio:
    mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

I don't understand why it complaints about >= 1.9.2, given my Ruby version is 1.9.3.

Maybe gem is ignoring the version set by RVM and reverting to the "base" one at OS level? How can I solve this and get apiaryio installed (which happens to be 1.8.7), please?

**EDIT**: I have tried also without using sudo, but I get also an error:

```
$ gem install apiaryio
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

Note the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/**1.8** directory... It seems that in that case is also looking for the base version in the OS, thus ignoring the 1.9 version set by RVM.

**EDIT2**: note that I'm sourcing rvm.sh before executing the above command. The complete procedure is as follows:

```
$ source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm use 1.9.3
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
$ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
$ which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/gem
$ gem install apiaryio
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551 directory.
```

In addition, I don't have any stuff related with RVM in `~/.bashrc` but I understand that the `source` command at the very beggining achieves the same effect.

Comment: Don't use `sudo`.

Comment: @TomLord thanks for the suggestion! I've tried also that way, without any luck. Question post has been edited to add the details.

Comment: Did you install `rvm` properly? It looks like you haven't, since `gem` is still running the *system* `gem` command, not the `rvm` version. Is there a line like `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in your `~/.bashrc` or similar? Have you sourced the `.bashrc`? What is the output of `which ruby`?

Comment: @TomLord thanks again for the feedback. Please, have a look to the EDIT2 block in the question post, I have added there all the relevant information you ask. I followed the procedure described in $ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby to install RVM, but maybe I did some mistake following it that is causing this problem.

Comment: I'm also adding `which gem` result... Surprisingly it seems to be used the one provided by rvm...

Comment: Note that your output of `gem install apiaryio` **CHANGED** after you sourced that file!!! This strongly indicates that you did not install `rvm` correctly. I would advise you to re-install it, following the documentation carefully. You've presumably messed up the file permissions by running things as `sudo`.

Comment: As a side note, is there a good reason why you're using ruby `1.9.3`? This is an *old* version, for which long-term support ended years ago. You should ideally be using at least `2.2.8`; and ideally the latest (`2.4.2`).

Comment: Reinstalling RVM and using 2.2.8 has worked. Self-answer published below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following @TomLord recommendations, after removing RVM (`rvm implode`) and reinstalling it in a cleaner way per-user, the problem has been solved.